# Measure of $E$ is the limit of the measure of the open set $\mathcal{O}_n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

> Suppose $E$ is a given set, and $\mathcal{O}_n$ is the open set: $$\mathcal{O}_n=\{x : d(x,E) < \frac 1n \}.$$ Show:
>
> (a) If $E$ is compact, then $m(E)=\lim_{n \to \infty} m(\mathcal{O}_n)$.
>
> (b) However, the condition in (a) may be false for $E$ closed and unbounded, or $E$ open and unbounded.

This is from Real Analysis, Stein and Shakarchi: Chapter 1, Exercise 7.

I am doing part (a) only.

(a)Since $E$ is compact, $E$ is closed, and so $E$ is measurable. Also, $\mathcal{O}_n$ is an open set as given, which menas $\mathcal{O}_n$ is measurable. If $x \in E$, then $d(x,E) = 0 < \frac 1n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $x \in \mathcal{O}_n$, and so $E \subset \mathcal{O}_n$. Finally, observe that $m(\mathcal{O}_n)$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded; hence, $m(\mathcal{O}_n)$ is convergent. By monotonicity, $m(E) \le m(\mathcal{O}_n)$, and so $m(E) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} m(\mathcal{O}_n)$.

**Question:** To establish equality, I must prove the reverse inequality. I have trouble with starting the proof for this. Can I receive a starting hint please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $E$ is compact so $E=\bar{E}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_{n}$. So you don't need to use monotonicity. Here $\bar{E}$ denotes closure.

Proof that $\bar{E}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_{n}$:

- If $x\in \bar{E}$ then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $y_{n}\in B(x,\frac{1}{n})\cap E\neq\emptyset$. Now $d(x,E)\leq d(x,y_{n})<\frac{1}{n}$ so $x\in O_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I.e. $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_{n}$.
- If $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_{n}$ then $d(x,E)<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. $d(x,E)=0$. Thus $x\in \bar{E}$.

Comment: Is this hint you provided for the reverse direction or the forward direction? Because I was thinking your statement of "you don't need to use monotonicity" is a remark to my forward direction suggests I should remove this fact, or if I don't use monotonicity in the reverse direction.

Comment: @dragon: There is no reverse inequality needed to prove. Since $E=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_{n}$ and $O_{n}\supseteq O_{n+1}$ for all $n$, then $m(E)=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(O_{n})$ by convergence of measure since $m(O_{1})<\infty$ as $E$ was compact. Are you aware of the result that if $O_{n}\supseteq O_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and $E=\bigcap O_{n}$, then $m(E)=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(O_{n})$ if $m(O_{1})<\infty$?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that $O_n \supset O_{n+1}$, which is why I stated in my work that $m(O_n)$ is a decreasing sequence, which is also lower bounded by $0$.

Comment: I think I got it now: Once we established that $E = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{O}_n$, and that $E$ and each $\mathcal{O}_n$ are measurable, we can take measure of them and conclude $$m(E) = m\left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{O}_n \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathcal{O}_n,$$ with the last inequality invoking the fact that $O_n$ is a nested sequence of sets. **Addendum:** I didn't look at the last part of your previous comment as of writing this one; I only viewed your updated answer. So apologies for duplicating here what you said in your comment.

Comment: @dragon: yeah, precisely what I meant. I'm glad you got it.